# Can we say that, for any $n\in\mathbb {R^{+}}$ following inequality is correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

My question is so elementary. But, I don't know correct answer.

> $f(n)$ and $f(n+\lambda)$ are finite functions and following fraction is convergent:
>
> If $0≤ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {f(\lfloor n \rfloor)}{ f(\lfloor n +\lambda \rfloor)} <1$  for $\lambda \in \mathbb {Z^{+}}$,  $ \left\{f(\lfloor n \rfloor), f(\lfloor n+\lambda \rfloor) \right\} \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Here $\lambda$ is a constant.

**Question:** Can we say that, for any $n\in\mathbb {R^{+}}$ following inequality is correct?

> $$\frac {f(\lfloor n \rfloor)}{ f(\lfloor n+\lambda \rfloor)}>\frac {f(\lfloor n+1\rfloor)}{ f(\lfloor n+1+\lambda \rfloor)}$$

I can not find a counterexample. For example $f(n)= 7^n, \lambda =1$. The rule is correct. I need a counterexample.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: @John Hunghes  but why??

Comment: If you had shown some effort on the problem yourself, I'm might have put more effort into an answer.

Comment: @John Hughes I am sorry, but this is not a homework.. Thank You

Comment: Is the condition on the limit supposed to be satisfies for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, or for a fixed given $\lambda$?

Comment: $\lambda$ is constant. @fishroe

Comment: The question of whether this is homework is irrelevant. The question, instead, is whether you put any work into this problem, and if you did what you found out, where you got stuck, etc.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Yes, I can say. I could not find a counterexample. Here I am stuck.

Comment: @Lee Mosher I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot. A sequence can converge without being monotonic.

Comment: I fixed Question. Thank you.